# Trying to create an in memory Word Doc with OpenXml says it's corrupt

Tags: c#, openxml

I've built an ActionResult to output data to a Word Document. I get no errors at compile or runtime, but when trying to open the file I get the message: 'We're sorry, We can't open filename.docx because we found a problem with its contents.'.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    //Create a response stream to create and write the Excel file
    HttpContext curContext = HttpContext.Current;
    curContext.Response.Clear();
    curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=text.docx");
    curContext.Response.Charset = "";
    curContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";

    //Write the stream back to the response
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    var repData = "<b>Mark's Test Book: With a Special Sub Title</b><br /><br /><b>Chapter: Chapter Title 1: Chapter Title sub</b><br /><br />";

    Document.CreateAndAddHtmlToWordprocessingStream(ms, repData);

    curContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);

    curContext.Response.End();

}
```

The static method is as follows:

```
public static void CreateAndAddHtmlToWordprocessingStream(Stream stream, string inputBody)
{
    // Open a WordProcessingDocument based on a stream.
    WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    // Add a main document part. 
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

    // Create the document structure.
    mainPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();

    // Create the document body.
    mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

    var ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body style=\"font-family:'Calibri';\">" + inputBody + "</body></html>"));

    var altChunkId = "id";
    var formatImportPart = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, altChunkId);

    formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);

    var altChunk = new AltChunk { Id = altChunkId };

    mainPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

    mainPart.Document.Save();

    // Close the document handle.
    wordprocessingDocument.Close();

    // Caller must close the stream.
}
```

I've looked at these two posts, but didn't find anything that helped:

[C# return memory stream from OpenXML resulting to a corrupted word file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255995/c-sharp-return-memory-stream-from-openxml-resulting-to-a-corrupted-word-file)

[Streaming In Memory Word Document using OpenXML SDK w/ASP.NET results in "corrupt" document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667513/streaming-in-memory-word-document-using-openxml-sdk-w-asp-net-results-in-corrup)

Comment: `ms.GetBuffer()` doesn't sound right... Usually you would do `ms.Position = 0;` and return the stream.  If you want to hit a byte array first, use `ms.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ms.GetBuffer()` will return the automatically managed and sized buffer.  This will start with the data you have written, but may contain extra `\0` bytes at the end in the eventuality you continue to `.Write()`.

To return a `MemoryStream`, you can use either of the following:

```
ms.Position = 0;
ms.CopyTo(curContext.Response.OutputStream);
```

or:

```
var msResult = ms.ToArray();
curContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(msResult, 0, msResult.Length);
```

Comment: I ended up doing this: ` ms.WriteTo(curContext.Response.OutputStream);` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that that solved your problem, you may consider accepting it as such by clicking the green checkmark under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a method like this to handle the memory stream and the filename formatting

```
private static void DynaGenWordDoc(string fileName, Page page, WordprocessingDocument wdoc)
{
    page.Response.ClearContent();
    page.Response.ClearHeaders();
    page.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    page.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.docx", fileName));

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        wdoc.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(page.Response.OutputStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
    }
    page.Response.Flush();
    page.Response.End();
}
```